# Combine MOV video files

Tags: ffmpeg, arch-linux, quicktime

I'm on Arch Linux 4.13.10 and I'd like to combine multiple `.MOV` files shot with a Canon EOS camera.

I tried to convert the files to transport streams (`.ts` files) using FFmpeg, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15908328/ffmpeg-to-combine-two-mov-files-from-iphone#15908441), but sound was missing from the resulting file.

I'd prefer if the resulting file would be `.mp4`, but this is not strictly required.

How do I do this?

Comment: See also: [Stack Overflow: How to concatenate two MP4 files using FFmpeg?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7333232/4561887)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I succeeded merging the files using [FFmpeg's demuxing feature](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate#demuxer). For `.mp4` conversion, I had to explicitly convert the audio stream to avoid this error:

> Could not find tag for codec pcm_s16le in stream #1, codec not currently supported in container

This is the command combining the files to `merged.mp4`:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i files_to_combine.txt -vcodec copy -acodec aac -strict -2 -b:a 384k merged.mp4
```

If the output file can be also a `.MOV` file, the command is:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i files_to_combine.txt -vcodec copy -acodec copy merged.MOV
```

Here's the content of the text file `files_to_combine.txt`:

```
file ./first_file.MOV
file ./second_file.MOV
```

---

If you get the error

> Unsafe file name 'file with spaces.mov'
> files_to_combine.txt: Operation not permitted

and trust the file names, you can add `-safe 0` to get around this error. See FFmpeg's [man page](https://manpages.org/ffmpeg):

```
ffmpeg -safe 0 -f concat ...
```

## Shorter commands

Trying the same task five years later, I also had success with

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i files_to_combine.txt merged.mov
```

and

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i files_to_combine.txt -f mp4 merged.mp4
```

Comment: From the single MOV, you can use [mp4box](https://gpac.wp.imt.fr/downloads/gpac-nightly-builds/) to get a MP4. `mp4box -add merged.mov -new merged.mp4`

Comment: I get: [concat @ 0x55ba4a488b40] Line 1: unknown keyword 'IMG_9847.MOV' files_to_combine.txt: Invalid data found when processing input

Comment: @NathanB: I'm pretty sure you forgot the keyword "file" in front of your file names in `files_to_combine.txt`.

Answer (score 3):

```
find *.MOV | sed 's:\ :\\\ :g'| sed 's/^/file /' > fl.txt; ffmpeg -f concat -i fl.txt -c copy output.mp4; rm fl.txt
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1069112)

Comment: No, it does many `.MOV` to single `.MP4` conversion

Comment: I had to change the output to .mov to get it to work, like: 

`find *.MOV | sed 's:\ :\\\ :g'| sed 's/^/file /' > fl.txt; ffmpeg -f concat -i fl.txt -c copy output.mov; rm fl.txt`

Comment: yes the fl.txt file should include in every line the word 'file ' before the file name

Comment: Upvoted because it's useful by having `-c copy` in it. but, without any explanation, this is a very poor answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for how to concatenate `.mp4` files instead, see my other answer here: [Stack Overflow: How to concatenate two MP4 files using FFmpeg?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74454448/4561887)

### To combine many `.mov` or `.MOV` files into one

...here's what you need to do:

```bash
# 0. Copy all .mov files that (you'd like to combine) into a single directory. 
# Then `cd` into that directory. 

# 1. Create a "files.txt" file containing a list of files to combine
find . -type f -iname "*.mov" | sort -V \
    | awk '{print "file \x27" $0 "\x27"}' > files.txt

# [WHAT I USUALLY USE: FAST]
# 2. **If all of your .mov files have the same encoding** (ex: they were 
# all recorded on the same video camera and with the same settings), you can
# specify to use the "copy" codec via `-c copy`, which means it will NOT 
# have to re-encode the video. This just concatenates all the files together. 
# THIS TAKES **SECONDS**. 
time ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i files.txt -c copy merged.mov 

# [SLOW; SOMETIMES NECESSARY]
# OR 2. **If each of your .mov files has a different encoding,** you'll need to 
# re-encode them all into a single stream. 
# - This uses the "files.txt" file created above, and outputs the merged 
#   file into "merged.mov". 
# THIS COULD TAKE **HOURS**. 
time ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i files.txt merged.mov
```

I am generally in a situation where I can use the first option, which takes *seconds* instead of *hours*, which is great!

### Extra details and explanation

- If `ls -1` shows you have these files:

  ```
  REC_0009.MOV
  REC_0010.MOV
  REC_0011.MOV
  ```

  Then the `find` command will produce this `files.txt` file:

  ```
  file './REC_0009.MOV'
  file './REC_0010.MOV'
  file './REC_0011.MOV'
  ```
- The `-iname "*.mov"` part does a case-*in*senstive* match for all files ending in `.mov` or `.MOV`, or any other combination of capital letters.
- If you forget `-safe 0` in the `ffmpeg` command, and any of your filenames have a "directory" in them in the form of `./` even, you'll get an error like this:

  ```bash
  [concat @ 0x555a24968700] Unsafe file name './REC_0009.MOV'
  files.txt: Operation not permitted
  ```

  The `-safe 0` option tells `ffmpeg` to ignore this error and accept "unsafe" directories in filepaths.

  [@Matthias Braun mentions that here.](https://superuser.com/a/1256224/425838)

  From the `ffmpeg` man page *online only* (*not* in the `man ffmpeg` man page locally on my Linux Ubuntu 20.04 computer): https://manpages.org/ffmpeg:

  > `safe`
  >
  > If set to `1`, reject unsafe file paths. A file path is considered safe if it does not contain a protocol specification and is relative and all components only contain characters from the portable character set (letters, digits, period, underscore and hyphen) and have no period at the beginning of a component.
  >
  > If set to `0`, any file name is accepted.
  >
  > The default is `1`.
  >
  > `-1` is equivalent to `1` if the format was automatically probed and `0` otherwise.
- The `-c copy` option tells `ffmpeg` to use the "copy" codec, which means it will not re-encode the video. This is what makes it so fast.

### References

1. I studied [@Matthias Braun's answer too](https://superuser.com/a/1256224/425838).
2. My answer here where I use `\x27` to produce the `'` character: [Stack Overflow: How to escape single quotes within single quoted strings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65878993/4561887)
3. I had a lot of talks with the GitHub Copilot AI in my VSCode text editor while figuring out the nuances of the commands above.
4. My answer for MP4 files: [Stack Overflow: How to concatenate two MP4 files using FFmpeg?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74454448/4561887)